# Clickable zone in an image with Qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt, image-processing, clickable-image

Is it possible to create clickable zones in an image with Qt (C++)?
I have an image, which I want to load it on Qt, and then select a clickable zone for.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `QGraphicsScene`, which can be displayed by a `QGraphicsView`. Add the image with `addPixmap()`. For the clickable area you could subclass e.g. `QGraphicsRectItem` and reimplement the `mousePressEvent()`. Add this item with `addItem()` to the graphics scene. You can even set a different cursor for the clickable area with `setCursor()`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the image itself is not a visual construct, it is just data which you draw onto something. If you draw it on a `QWidget` you have virtual functions for mouse events, which provide you with information about the cursor position and buttons.

It depends on the stack you are willing to use. Qt provides the good old `QWidget`, the associated but slightly more in-depth `QGraphicsView`, and last but not least - QML, where it is even easier - just use a `Image` element and put a `MouseArea` which fills it and there you have it.